# Leak Canary is not working

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I want to add leak canary to a test project. I created a project and did the steps from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VKBjlHtKMY

When I'm trying `wrongWay()`, the message *"Dumping Memory app will freeze"* is appearing in the emulator Nexus_5X_API_23. When I'm trying `rightWay()`, the same message is appearing too. There is no message *"Dumping Memory app will freeze"* in video when author using `rightWay()`.

I cant understand why?

Where can I find a good tutorial about Leak Canary or other Leak Memory library.

So build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vopolski.myleakcanary"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vopolski.myleakcanary">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".LeakCanaryApplication">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

LeakCanaryApplication.java

```
package com.example.vopolski.myleakcanary;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.SystemClock;

import com.squareup.leakcanary.LeakCanary;
import com.squareup.leakcanary.RefWatcher;

public class LeakCanaryApplication extends Application {

    private RefWatcher refWatcher;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        refWatcher = LeakCanary.install(this);
    }

    public static RefWatcher getRefWatcher(Context context) {
        LeakCanaryApplication application =
                (LeakCanaryApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
        return application.refWatcher;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.vopolski.myleakcanary;

import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.squareup.leakcanary.LeakCanary;
import com.squareup.leakcanary.RefWatcher;
import android.app.Application;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String msg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rightWay();


    }

    private void rightWay() {
        new MyThread().start();
    }

    private class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    private void wrongWay() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true){
                    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: got anything on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add the following to your Activity onDestroy method

```
RefWatcher refWatcher = MyApplication.getRefWatcher(this);
refWatcher.watch(this);
```

You can refer to following URL  https://github.com/square/leakcanary/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing the rightWay() wrong.

MyThread should be static, otherwise it's a non-static inner class, and implicitly references the outer class Activity. The thread runs forever, so the activity won't be GCed. This is a memory leak.